# How to use node reference to link images of referenced node?

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I created a blog content type. In this content type I added a field "blog detail". I have a custom module to fetch data using `node_load()` in blog page. Now I want, when I click on a particular image, that this image's basic page would open using `node_reference()`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'ld suggest you use [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references). Add a node reference field into your blog content type. Finally when creating a blog node you'll reference a basic page (the one with your image).

Then check the display settings of your node reference field. Check the field formatters where you can choose

- Title (linked)
- Rendered Node
- NID
- etc...

Exactly there you have to add a field formatter now. Best by writing a small custom module. You may take the following code as a starting point:

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
*/
function MY_MODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  $info = array(
    'linked_image' => array( // Machine name of the formatter
      'label' => t('Image (linked)'), 
      'field types' => array('node_reference'), // Scope (this one will only be available to node reference fields)
      'description' => t('Display linked image if available'),
    ), 
  );
  return $info;
}

/**
* Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
*/
function MY_MODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      // get the nid,
      // do a node_load(),
      // get your image,
      // rework it
      // $linked_image = what ever you got
      $element[$delta]['#markup'] = $linked_image;
    }
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: hey, can you just provide the briefly code? I will try but I didn't understand after foreach

Comment: @priyank - Sure, if you hire me ;)

Comment: please help me bro.

Comment: @priyank - Don't you think I already helped you lot? Now go on and help yourself. It will pay off a thousand times if you figure out to walk the last few meters by yourself. Or simply ask a new question and let's see where your exact problem is with that code.

Comment: @priyank : I think you should consider marking this anwers as accepted ... Moreover, and sorry for asking, but since you don't seem to have any question marked as accepted, I wonder if you're familar with [this]( http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?